# Can't start AVD

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, haxm

erro info：

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'Nexus5'
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX is not installed on this machine (/dev/HAX is missing).
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need the Intel HAXM. Open the SDK Manager and install the `Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM Installer)`

After that, open your SDK directory and open the DMG file located inside `extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager`. Then run the installer contained inside.

After that you may check if HAXM is running via `kextstat | grep intel`

If Intel HAXM is operating correctly, the command will show a status message indicating that the kernel extension named "com.intel.kext.intelhaxm" is loaded.

To stop or start Intel HAXM, use the following commands:

- Stop: `sudo kextunload –b com.intel.kext.intelhaxm`
- Start: `sudo kextload –b com.intel.kext.intelhaxm`

Comment: I have installed HAXM, but when I run kextstat | grep intel it shows Executing: /usr/bin/kmutil showloaded
No variant specified, falling back to release